# The message exceeds the maximum supported size

Tags: c#, rest, outlook, office365api

I'm using `Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.OutlookServicesClient` from `Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices` library to work with Office 365 Outlook AAD.

When I try to get one of messages by its message-ID an error occurs :

> "{"error":{"code":"ErrorMessageSizeExceeded","message":"The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the maximum supported size."}}".

Is there any way to fix this error?

Here is the code below that I use to get a message:

```
var messageQuery = m_user.Messages[messageSummary.MessageId];
IMessage message = await messageQuery.ExecuteAsync();
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com is English only. Please translate the title of your question or use the Russian StackOverflow available at http://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: It seems like you need to increase the message size via Exchange Admin:  https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=how+to+Change+message+size+limits+in+Office+365.&oq=how+to+Change+message+size+limits+in+Office+365.&gs_l=serp.3...12703.13325.0.13510.7.7.0.0.0.0.170.856.2j5.7.0....0...1.1.64.serp..5.1.110...30i10.ShuJgycY1eQ